# Import ES6 dependency inside class constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a JS/ES6 class with a constructor that needs to dynamically load a dependency based on the settings passed to it.

It works perfectly with CommonJS syntax:

```js
class Example {
    handler = null;

    constructor(dependency) {
        try {
            this.handler = new (require(dependency))();
        } catch {
            throw new Error(`${dependency} not installed`);
        }
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

However, I haven't been able to get it to work properly in ES6 module format.  Here's as far as I've been able to get to:

```js
class Example {
    handler = null;

    constructor(dependency) {
        try {
            this.handler = new (await import(dependency)).default();
        } catch {
            throw new Error(`${dependency} not installed`);
        }
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

This doesn't work because you cannot use `await` without `async`, and a class constructor cannot be `async`.

Without `await`, further code tends to fail, as there is no guarantee the dependency has been loaded in time.

I cannot load the dependency outside of the class in the ordinary way, because it can be essentially any arbitrary dependency the consumer of the class defines.

I would *prefer* not to have a separate init/build method that the consumer needs to worry about.  Ideally, you should be able to just do `const ex = new Example('some-dependency')` and then have instant access to the methods of the class in `ex`, without any need for further boilerplate on the consumer side.

The constructor could of course call a static build method, but that seems to just be moving the asynchronous problem to a different location.

Is there an established pattern or a kludgey hack to achieve this in ES6 modules?

Comment: if you can't use async then use Promise

Comment: If you're dynamically importing then you're opting into async behavior. Can you export a `async function createExample(dependency) { const dep = await import(dependency); return new Example(dep); }` instead? Otherwise your only option would be for whatever uses `this.handler` to be async and for that code to be the thing that throws if the import fails.